# init a git branch with stuff from outside the directory

Tags: git, tfs, git-branch

I have a git repository which has a folder called branches which literally contains different branches of the repo from TFS. This was migrated from TFS to git.

I am trying to create new git branches in this new git repo using the branch in the branch folder. Is there a way of doing it ?

Comment: E.g 

repository 1 -> folder1
repository 2 -> folder2

any way of making folder1 from repo1 as the branch for repo2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### NOTE: This doesn't bring in your TFS history.

This is how I'd do it if you just wanted the branches from TFS represented as branches in git. This isn't going to bring all your TFS history over--if you need that you need to use a tool like `git-tfs` ([Link](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs)).

#### How to create git branches that correspond to your TFS branches (sans history)

For the sake of argument, let's pretend your folder structure looks like this:

```
/ (Root folder)
  Solution/
    ProjectA/
      Files
    ProjectB/
      Files
  Branches/
     Branch1_SomeBranch/
       Solution/
     Branch2_SomeOtherBranch/
       Solution/
```

1. Move the `branches` folder to another directory (i.e. `mkdir ../OldBranches/; mv Branches ../OldBranches/`)
2. Run `git status`, you should see that the content in the **branches** folder is **deleted**
3. `git add -A; git commit -m "Removing branches folder"`
4. **Make a new branch for Branch1**: `git checkout -b SomeBranch`
5. Delete the contents of the repo (all except the `.gitignore` and `.git/` folder!). So the only thing your repositiory sees is 1 folder and 1 file.
6. **Commit**: `git add -A; git commit -am "Cleaning out repo to recreate SomeBranch"`
7. **Copy contents of SomeBranch into Repo**: i.e. `cp -r ../OldBranches/Branch1_SomeBranch/* .` Now you should see a `~/Solution/ProjectA` and `~/Solution/ProjectB` in your repo.
8. **Add and commit**: `git add -A; git commit -m "Imported the branch from TFS"`
9. **Make a new branch for Branch2**: `git checkout -b SomeOtherBranch`
10. **Repeat steps 5-8 for SomeOtherBranch**. Just remember to change step 7 slightly to copy from `Branch2_SomeOtherBranch`

Continue doing this until all your branches are in git.

#### Side Note on git history

Git keeps track of all your history. If you add a file to git it's pretty much there forever. Every git clone has this history. If your branches folder is large and contains a lot of large files, you'll notice some long `git clone` operations and a large `.git/` folder. If this is a new repository that doesn't have a lot of history, it may be worthwhile to do this with a new git repo. Basically I'd do:

1. Move branches into another folder
2. Create new git repo: `git init`
3. Set up appropriate `.gitignore` file.
4. Commit to master: `git add -A; git commit -m "Initial commit of what was in TFS in main branch"
5. Repeat steps 4-10 from above.

Comment: Well, I used your method and it works in creating the branch but the history is not kept intact. The new branch has no chnageset history but just the latest one.

Comment: Dang, a downvote for something you didn't ask for?

You didn't specify you wanted history in your question. Follow the instructions here:

http://blog.simontimms.com/2013/04/02/importing-a-git-repository-into-tfs/

I won't add any more to this answer because I put too much work in already and two downvotes is discouraging.

Comment: A for effort...also IMPORTING A GIT REPOSITORY INTO TFS? I am doing the opposite.]

Comment: You're right. I pasted the wrong link. I meant git-tfs at https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs

Comment: sorry had to un-accept the answer as I found the legit way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: This brings in your Git history for that subdirectory.**

Found the way to do this while maintaining the history.

To repeat - I have Repo1 -> Folder1 , Folder2 and Repo2 -> Folder1, folder2. I want to take out Folder1 from Repo1 and make it as a branch for Repo 2 while maintaining all the individual history of that one folder.

The way to do it :

1. **Make a clone of Repo1** in your local so that you don't lose any stuff from it.
2. Use the command `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter foodir -- --all` to basically **remove all the commits that didn't touch that subdirectory** hence leaving a core git repository with just that one sub-directory(Folder1) with all its commits.
3. Now **init a branch in Repo2**.
4. **Push Repo1**(which now consists of just that sub-directory and its change set history) **as a branch to Repo2**
5. You're done.

Answer (score -1):

No, there isn't a way to do this

Comment: I would mark your question with the correct answer but the above guy put more effort into his answer. Also yes, there is a way to do it. I used a mix of git-tfs to import all branches with history from tfs to git and them filtered this one folder i needed using git-cli and finally merged that with the new repository as a branch. A hack, but works.